# Validate URL Parameters in an Openapi 3.0 Spring Boot RESTful API?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, validation, openapi, url-parameters

In my openapi spec I specify URL parameters for a specific resource path like so:

```
paths:
  /some/path:
    get:
      summary: some summary 
      parameters:
        name: usefulParameter
        description:
        schema:
          type: string
          maxLength: 15
```

Using openapi 3.0 codegen I generate a Spring Boot RESTful API which automatically generates an interface with a name like xxxxDelegate, which has methods that must be implemented like:

```
default ResponseEntity<Object> somePathGet(String usefulParameter) {
    getRequest().ifPresent(request -> {
        for (MediaType mediaType: MediaType.parseMediaTypes(request.getHeader("Accept"))) {
            if (mediaType.isCompatibleWith(MediaType.valueOf("application/json"))) {
                String exampleString = "null";
                ApiUtil.setExampleResponse(request, "application/json", exampleString);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
}
```

Which has a comment at the top of the interface stating:

> A delegate to be called by the {@link YourApiController}}.
> Implement this interface with a {@link org.springframework.stereotype.Service} annotated class.

So I do exactly that, which results in my own class which looks like this:

```
@Service
public class MyCustomClass implements xxxxDelegate {
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Object> somePathGet(String usefulParameter) {
    }
}
```

So far this works **perfectly**. I can invoke it and log the input parameter. The issue that I'm having is that I can't seem to find documentation anywhere on how to **assign validation to that input parameter** - the Openapi 'maxLength' is not being applied, and Spring/Spring Boot doesn't seem to provide a way to apply validation to these parameters unless you use Model type classes and annotate the members. I would prefer to avoid that and instead simply tell the API that **this URL parameter requires specific validation, such as min/max length, or a certain character set**.

Is this possible?

Comment: were you able to resolve this? Facing similar issue

Comment: No sorry, never found a solution. Please update me if you fine one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
x-field-extra-annotation: "@Email"
```

in field definitions of the api-defining yaml. Self-defined validators are possible if you put them into the `org.openapitools.model` package.

In the server-side API-implementation you need to put the `@Valid` annotation in front of any parameter you want to have validated.

Here is an example for an UUID scheme with custom validation (note that the validation rules defined in the yaml have no effect on the generated Spring-Java-Code):

```
  schemas:
    UUID:
      description: "Format: UUID"
      type: "string"
      pattern: '^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}$'
      minLength: 36
      maxLength: 36
      example: "097c9a34-ec4c-4766-b29b-f528db4a3ef8"
      x-field-extra-annotation: "@UUID"
```